# Delete from <tablename> where <columname> Like <value> MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010, sql-delete

I am using the following code to filter out some columns in my taglist:

```
DELETE FROM TagSubs
WHERE TAGNAME LIKE '*\CMD\*' OR '*\PAR\*'
```

Now I thought this would just delete all the rows that are made up like this:

```
SLKRSL1_S1\SVS_AK\UVS01\CMD\BPO_ID
```

and

```
SLKRSL1_S1\SVS_AK\IVS01\PAR\Knipper_Tijd
```

But for some reason, it just deletes every row I have. Also the ones that are like this:

```
SLKRSL1_S1\SVS_AK\KKL\STS\Status
```

Wich doesn't even contain \cmd\ or \par\

What is the reason my code doesnt work as I would want it to work?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this,

```
DELETE 
FROM TagSubs
WHERE TAGNAME LIKE '*\CMD\*' OR 
      TAGNAME LIKE '*\PAR\*'
```

Comment: I tried this, and it did not work with the % but instead i used the *, wich made it work. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Edited the question for future reference ;) to avoid this confusion

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
DELETE FROM TagSubs WHERE TagSubs.TAGNAME LIKE '%\CMD\%' OR TagSubs.TAGNAME LIKE '%\PAR\%'
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms179859.aspx